# React-Native Bar chart Customized

Tags: react-native, react-chartjs

I am new to react-native. I need to place charts in my app (Bar, multi-line, multi-bar). What can be the best library to use and I want Bar chart with curvy edges not with the regular style. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please see if below libraries are helpful

- https://github.com/tomauty/react-native-chart
- https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-native
- https://github.com/wuxudong/react-native-charts-wrapper
- https://github.com/capitalone/react-native-pathjs-charts

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you @David. I will check them.

Comment: I would like to add one more to the above list - [react-native-gifted-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gifted-charts).

It is a complete charts solution in react native- Bar, Line, Area, Pie, Donut, Stack, Multi-Bar, Multi-Line, Multi-Area, combined Bar with Line, etc. Also, it allows highly performant animations and 3D effects.
With its detailed [documentation](https://gifted-charts.web.app/) and ease of implementation, it's a best fit for beginners as well as pros.